# Get Wrapping Cell When Clicking Button In Customized Cell

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

So I designed my own customized cell which contains an image, text label and a button.
The class for the custom cell is `Facility`
When I click the button, I invoke the function:

```
- (IBAction)infoButtonClicked:(id)sender {
    //Here I would like to get the string of the text label
}
@end
```

Does anyone know how I can do it?

Thanks

Comment: What class is the `-infoButtonClicked:` method in currently?

Comment: Ohh it's self silly me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your method is being called in the same class as the label is, you can access your property (outlet) for that label.

```
- (IBAction)infoButtonClicked:(id)sender {
    NSString *textLabelString = self.myTextLabel.text;
}
```

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you didn't explain the code. If you do explain it (in your answer), you are far more likely to get more upvotes—and the questioner is more likely to learn something!

Comment: Added an explanation.